# Google app engine + Go + REST service

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, go

How to do this in GAE + Go

```
http.HandleFunc("/ChatGetMessages/{user}/{pass}", ServiceHandler)
```

Then in the "ServiceHandler" have access to "user" and "pass".

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you seek can be found in the MUX package of the [gorilla toolkit](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org).